# Need to add the ability of instantiation of pod in Openshift with additional PVC

Tags: java, openshift, fabric8, openshift-client-tools

I would like to add PVC dynamically without rebuilding the image. Does anyone know about some practice how to do that?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Addition of a persistent volume has got nothing to do with building an image.

You need to configure the deployment config to mount the persistent volume into the container for the pod created. This can be done through the web console, or using `oc set volume` on the command line.

Suggest you have a read through:

- https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/

which has a chapter about working with persistent storage.